# Django App - Ajax Auto-complete After 2 Characters and 1s Delay

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I have this piece of code in my Django app to create simple auto-complete search suggestion box. How do I limit the `Ajax` to at least 2 characters and how can I add lets say 1sec delay for the `Ajax` to execute the search query?

```
$(function(){

$('#search').keyup(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/search/",
        data: { 
            'search_text' : $('#search').val(),
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
        },
        success: searchSuccess,
        dataType: 'html'
    });

});

});

function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    $('#search-results').html(data);
}
```

Comment: Why would you need a 1sec delay? A common case is to trigger ajax only when min chars and value has changed.

Comment: I guess you are right, the 1sec delay is probably not necessary, I just thought it would give the user more time to type the keyword without triggering the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `#search` is probably a text input field, you can add the following code right before your ajax request:

```
// get the value that the user has typed
var v = $(this).val();
// don\'t go on if less than 3 chars or 
// some other key was pressed that did not change the data
if (v.length < 3 || v == $(this).data('prev-val')) return;
// set the old value as the new one
$(this).data('prev-val', v);
// now call ajax
```

Following a comment in the question, this does not deal with any time delay. A timer could easily be used to trigger the ajax request, and cancel any previous timer before setting a new one. But this would probably make matters more complicated for no good reason.

Comment: Excellent, this works! Also, is there a way to clear the suggestion box if the user delete the keyword? Because right now, the suggestion window stay open with the 3 char search results value even if I delete the keyword completely. Perhaps the window can also close on click away from the search box?

Comment: I am very glad! This is how I do it in my apps anyway. You can add a condition right before the `if` of this answer with something like `if (!v.length) $('#my-selector').hide();`. You would need to `.show()` again on ajax success though (or sth fancy like `fadeIn()`).

Comment: the hide function is working, but I'm not quite sure where to add the `.show()`. Can you be more specific how I can reset the search with the `.show()` on Ajax success?

Comment: In the `searchSuccess` function add a `$('#my-selector').show()`.

Comment: Got it! Thanks again for your time and your patience!